# Black screen after resume?

Tags: linux-mint, suspend

I have an Asus laptop (Cr400) running Mint 17.1.  If the machine is put into sleep and then resumed, I get a black screen.  I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> -<kbd>Opt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a command line, but that hangs at a flashing cursor before asking for a password.  Switching back to <kbd>F7</kbd> gives a flashing cursor.  I can no longer SSH into the machine.  Is there a solution?

Comment: The network is likely down after the resume, so no ssh makes sense. The black screen sounds like problem with resuming the graphic adapter (on of the more common problems with resuming). Post more information about the configuration: hardware, version of X11 and of the graphic driver in use.

Comment: @peterph Usually the network should come up automatically. It does depend on the network configuration however. Joe, what method do you use to suspend (are you closing the lid, or using a menu entry or what)?

Comment: @Gilles I am simply closing the lid.  Regarding the hanging at a cursor, let me elaborate:  It prompts for the username, and then hangs before asking for the password.  Graphics driver is the proprietary Nvidia driver.

Comment: @Gilles The other strange thing is that if I close it, let the sleep LED begin flashing, and then open it up again after about 5 seconds, it resumes fine.  The problem is when I leave it in sleep for a few minutes.

Comment: @JoeAltair Do you have the same problem if you suspend from a menu? And if you run `sudo pm-suspend` from the command line in a text console (Ctrl+Alt+F1)? What if you log into a text console, then go back to the GUI and close the lid, and come back to the text console, can you run programs there? Better yet, run the program `htop` before suspending, and see if it locks up, or if there's a process taking a lot of CPU time (press `P` to sort by CPU time).